# Google Server Side Tracking: Load analytics.js through tagging server

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have set up Server-Side Tracking with GA4 and GTM. After following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/dependency-serving?tag=gtm), I managed to load the gtag.js via my tagging server metrics.example.com . That's what the source tab in Chrome inspector shows (see picture).

Now, I am surprised that the analytics.js is still loaded via the Google server. I configured GTM so that all dependend scripts should be loaded via the tagging server. Thus, I expected analytics.js to be loaded via the tagging server as well. Is that expectation wrong? After hours of searching I didn't find a single tutorial or YT video that shows, that the analytics.js is actually loaded via tagging server. They all just show that for gtag.js. Can someone just tell me if he/she managed to load analytics.js via the tagging server?

[image: gtag.js loaded via tagging server. analytics.js via google server]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a misunderstanding. analytics.js is serving Universal Analytics which is not being loaded Server Side. GA4 was already being loaded from my own tagging server